# Displaying Facebook image from Facebook graph image

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-imageview, picasso, android-glide

I am having a image:
http://graph.facebook.com/1686132181448230/picture/?type=large

I am trying to load in Glide and Picasso

**With Glide:**

```
 Glide.with(activity)
 .load(userImage)
 .into(holder.userImgId);
```

**With Picasso:**

```
Picasso.with(activity)
.load(userImage)
.into(holder.userImgId);
```

**What is happening**:
I am not able to display the image.
.

**Analysis**:

- When I hit the
  Url(http://graph.facebook.com/1686132181448230/picture/?type=large)
  in browser.
- Its redirecting to
  url(https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12191684_981188781942577_3548797109795289791_n.jpg?oh=93fa9dcc9c1410863cfc4c25eef46bfd&oe=5B481F2F)

Its working in browser but not in library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358795/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311123/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841825/8089770